# How to split multiline string into lines?

Tags: javascript, string, special-characters

How to split a multiline string into lines without taking into account the newline in the line itself?

My approach is not working:

```
const str = `
Hello
World\t
its\nbeautiful
`;

JSON.stringify(str).split(/$\\n/g)
```

What is the result of this approach:

```
[""", "Hello", "World\t", "its", "beautiful", """]
```

What result is needed in the end:

```
[""", "Hello", "World\t", "its\nbeautiful"]
```

Comment: New line character here `its\nbeautiful` will be treated like a newline character. If you wish it to be printed like normal, you'll have to escape during input

Comment: But how can this be solved by writing a clearer regex?

Comment: Its not about regex. Its about string. New lines in string template are replaced as `\n`. So both would look same while processing

Comment: There is no way for regex to differentiate between intended and unintended newlines. It can't read your mind. Instead, encode your "special" newlines differently so that they can be distinguished from normal newlines.

Comment: This is sad, because in my case it is not possible to select "special" lines

Answer (score 1):

Since `\n` is the character that marks new lines, just like a normal new line, there is no way for javascript to differenciate between `\n` and `\n`.

An idea for your "special" new lines could be to escape that `\n` with another \ so you would end up with

```
const str = `
Hello
World\t
its\\nbeautiful
`;
str.split("\n");
```

The result would be this:

```
['', 'Hello', 'World\t', 'its\\nbeautiful', '']
```